# Rendered water looks different in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I followed a tutorial on god rays as I thought would make my project more interesting (I had a cube with a water material on it before and it didn't look as good) and since it starts with a plane and an ocean modifier the only way to square it is to get a cube and add a boolean to the plane (which is later extruded down). In viewport it looks great but when I render absolutely nothing shows, and there's a line close to the chest.

here's the blender file if it helps
https://pasteall.org/blend/cfc4ee3a0d7f4caf8ef8e890b027f98b

this is the viewport:

[image]

this is render:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modifiers have **different settings for the viewport and the render**. In your case, you have set the viewport settings higher than the render. That's why the render looks different (worse).

- the *Ocean* modifier has a value of 24 for *Viewport Resolution* but only 7 for *Render*. That's the reason why the god rays are less prominent. Set it to 24 for both.
- you have hidden the *water* object in viewport but not for render. This makes the scene look very different. Click the *camera* icon in the outline to hide it.
- the corals have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier that has level 3 for viewport but only level 2 for render. Set them also to 3 for render.

[image: settings]

Rendered image:

[image: rendered image]

Comment: thank you so much, fixing it right now!!!!!